# SQL Agent Run SSIS package as Administrator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, watin, sql-agent

I'm trying to run a SQL Agent Job with a step that is a SSIS File, and I need this step to be run as administrator.

My Package uses a Script task to download a file, as a Browser i Use [WATIN](http://watin.org/).

I'm using a thread to start this browser because this browser control requires the thread to be set as Single-Threaded Apartment.

This browser control is requiring to be run as administrator.

I've already created a *Credential* for a user that is Windows Admin, a *Proxy SSIS* account. (SQL Agent user is not windows admin).

But the SSIS package is not run as administrator yet.
I'm suspecting this is related to UAC.

Some details:

- SQL Agent Account is not Windows Administrator
- Using Windows Server 2008 R2
- My Package is run from the File System.
- The Package only works on BIDS if I run it as an Administrator (if not admin doesn't work)
- The Proxy account the job step is configured to run is windows admin.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this in another way, The problem wasn't related to running the package as administrator, but creating a windows and setting focus to it, however I had the option to see the result file on the web page and I managed to use it, without downloading it, thus not needing to set focus on the download windows.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SSIS runs in BIDS but not with SQL Agent](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/ssis-runs-in-bids-but-not-with-sql-agent) for some ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the user account in SSIS administrator group which can solve your problem.